# FFMPEG: How to enable libvorbis and libvpx on centos

Tags: ffmpeg

I have used following command to install libvorbis and libvpx.

```
yum install libvpx
yum install libvorbis
```

Please help me to enable these modules. I'm using centos 7 server.

Comment: You need the `devel` versions of those packages. I don't know whether they're available for CentOS but you can always manually compile them: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos

Comment: @aergistal I have fixed that but still unable to concat the videos. I'm running following command "ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i video.txt -c:v libvpx -c:a libvorbis -c copy output.webm"

Comment: Getting error :  Only VP8 or VP9 or AV1 video and Vorbis or Opus audio and WebVTT subtitles are supported for WebM.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument

Comment: The last matching `c` option overrides all the previous set values and in your case you have `-c copy` which copies everything without re-encoding. Either put it first or remove it.

Comment: I run "ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i video.txt -c:v libvpx -c:a libvorbis output.webm" command but getting error "Unknown encoder 'libvpx'" @aergistal

Comment: Codec is not enabled (try `ffmpeg -codecs | grep libvpx`). Are you using the nux dextop repo?

Comment: I used these steps to install the FFMPEG: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-centos-7/ @aergistal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189189/discussion-between-saurabh-sharma-and-aergistal).

Answer (score 2):

## 1. Remove the old ffmpeg

Uninstall the packages you installed from the [link](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-centos-7/) you followed. This should also remove the third-party repository you installed.

```
yum remove epel-release ffmpeg ffmpeg-devel
```

Remove the signing key you imported:

```
sudo rpm -e gpg-pubkey-85c6cd8a-4e060c35
sudo rm /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-nux.ro
```

## 2. Get a new ffmpeg

Now you can get a more recent `ffmpeg` that has libvpx, libvorbis (and libopus). You have two options–download or compile:

### If you want to download ffmpeg

For Linux and you can get it from [johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/).

```
curl -LO https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-git-amd64-static.tar.xz
tar xvf ffmpeg-git-amd64-static.tar.xz
cd ffmpeg-git-201*
sudo cp {ffmpeg,ffprobe} /usr/local/bin
```

For Windows or macOS see [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html).

### If you want to compile ffmpeg

See [FFmpeg Wiki: CentOS](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos).

---

### Consider using VP9 and Opus instead of outdated VP8 and Vorbis:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libvpx-vp9 -c:a libopus output.webm
```

For more info see FFmpeg Wiki: [VP9](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9) & [VP8](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP8).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Should I clone the following command to get the compiled ffmpeg "git clone https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg". Then put this into /usr/local/bin.

Comment: @SaurabhSharma No. That would download the source code but not a compiled ffmpeg. I updated the answer with detailed steps for rote usage that you can copy and paste.